# Pyramid 1.2 on Google App Engine causes import error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pylons, pyramid

I'm trying to run Pyramid on GAE by following the steps outlined [here](http://code.google.com/p/bfg-pages/wiki/PyramidTutorial). Everything works fine on dev server, but when deployed to Google's servers, the following error occurs:

```
<type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: cannot import name BaseRequest
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/.../0-0-1.353634463095353211/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pyramid.config import Configurator
  File "/base/data/home/apps/.../0-0-1.353634463095353211/lib/dist/pyramid/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pyramid.request import Request
  File "/base/data/home/apps/.../0-0-1.353634463095353211/lib/dist/pyramid/request.py", line 6, in <module>
    from webob import BaseRequest
```

This is probably caused by the fact that GAE uses WebOb 0.9 while Pyramid uses WebOb 1.1 (it resides under `lib/dist/webob` in my project), since `BaseRequest` is missing in 0.9.

In the `main.py` file there is this fragment:

```
sys.path.insert(0,'lib/dist')
```

but it seems to help only for dev server case. I there a way to force GAE runtime to use version 1.1 included in my application?

Answer (score 1):

It's not really a solution, per-se, but we're about to release the new Python runtime, Python 2.7, which includes updated versions of libraries, including webob 1.1. Perhaps you could target your app against that, instead of against the 2.5 runtime?

Comment: @bdonlan We've announced it will be part of 1.5.5, and we've just released the preview/prerelease for that. Prereleases are generally offered from a couple of weeks to a month ahead of the general release.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the runtime update, I found another workaround. I've renamed the WebOb 1.1 module from `webob` to `webobx` and made pyramid reference the renamed `webobx` module. Not very elegant and will have to be repeated if I get to upgrade pyramid, but works.